# Show my when my improvement requests have been acted on

Tags: feature-request, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/users/57159/ian-ringrose?tab=documentation&sort=requestsforimprovement lets me see all my improvement requests, but does not show if a request has been acted on.  This could easy be shown in a "current status" column.