# Improvement requests need to be improved

Tags: feature-request, documentation

There are some issues at the moment with improvement requests in Documentation.

Sometimes improvement requests stay around even thought they've been handled (because editors forget to dismiss them or don't use the "edit topic" button in the request before editing). If I see something like that I'd like to be able to dismiss the request but also leave a comment for future reviewers, so that they can also consider dismissing the request.

Similar questions:

- [allow comments on improvement requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328595/add-a-way-to-comment-on-improvement-requests)
- [require reason when dismissing a request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330041/in-documentation-someone-should-have-to-provide-a-reason-for-dismissing-a-reques)
- [show current status of my requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329431/show-my-when-my-improvement-requests-have-been-acted-on)

Comment: "but also leave a comment for future reviewers, so that they can also consider dismissing the request." -- I guess they have this in mind already, judging by the mockup towards the end of the last update: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th I made a somewhat related FR (about dismissing one's own requests): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332722/let-me-edit-my-own-improvement-request